# Common testcases for NFC and OCR testing both manual and automation

Tags: testcase

I'm testing an identity app that uses both OCR and NFC. Testing physical cards like passport, driver's license, and ID card. Are there common tetscases for both manual and automation to strictly check the implementation of these technologies work fine?

Comment: What risks are you investigating? Which information about the status of implementation are you trying to extract?